# How do I create and display an Access 2010 database on a web server?

Tags: mysql, sql, ms-access, search

I need to display my database table on my web server (supports php, SQL and MySQL etc)... I want a simple search and display the results of just 1 feild. How do I set up the query and how do I implement it onto the website? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'd move your data from Access to mySQL.. and then use Dreamweaver wizards to help to generate the forms that you need.

You can't run an Access database from a linux host.